# Java TCP Socket programming throwing IO exceptions

Tags: java

I have written a client-server TCP Socket program such that the client will enter a string and that will be displayed by the server(echo program)... the condition is when I enter bye the program should exit... Well and good  the client program is exiting ... but the server program is exiting with a java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF() and readFully exceptions.. plz help me.. whats wrong in the code...

```
/*Client*/

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class echoclient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    Socket soc = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4000);
    OutputStream sout = soc.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    while(true)
    {
    String message = din.readLine();
    if(message.equals("bye"))
        break;
    out.writeUTF(message);
    }
    soc.close();
}
```

}

```
   /*Server*/
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class echoserver {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4000);
    Socket soc = server.accept();
    System.out.println("Server Started....");

    InputStream sin = soc.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
    while(true)
    {
    String fromClient = in.readUTF();
    if(fromClient.equals("bye"))
        {break;}
    System.out.println("Client says : "+fromClient);
    }
    soc.close();server.close();
}
 }
```

Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
at echoserver.main(echoserver.java:15)
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could provide us with the exception.

Comment: @JunedAhsan - out.writeUTF() from the client and in.readUTF() on the server

Comment: This is the exception I get:

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is that that's just what happens.  The `EOFException` is the *only* way that the `DataInputStream` tell the caller that it has reached EOF.  So if your server attempts to read when the socket has been closed by your client, that's what will happen.

There are two solutions:

- Catch and handle the EOFException.
- Modify your "protocol" so that the client (somehow) tells the server when it has sent the last message ... and is going to close the socket.

---

Closing the `DataOutputStream` on the client side is a good idea, but it probably won't solve the problem.  A `DataOutputStream` is not buffered and neither is a Socket's `OutputStream`, so there should be no data to be flushed.  (Any data outstanding data in the network protocol stack should be transmitted when the `Socket` or `OutputStream` is closed.)

Comment: Can you plz help me in how to modify the protocol?

Comment: I recommend that you handle the exception.  But there are a variety of ways to modify the protocol.  For instance, an empty String could mean EOF coming, as could some special string value.  Or you could send a boolean after each string that is `true` or `false` depending on whether an EOF is coming.

Comment: I made it as try and (empty) catch block. But will that be a good idea? To be frank i am not satisfied because all my lab programs are based on this only.

Comment: I don't know enough about what you are trying to do (in the big picture) so I can't say if it is a good idea.  It depends on what your server needs to do when a client connection ends.  It also depends on whether your server needs to distinguish between the client shutting down deliberately ... or just dying.

Comment: I just need that my server should exit smoothly without any exceptions thats all...

Comment: In that case, catching the exception and causing the server to exit seems fine.